# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'https' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php

I have an editable page contact portion and when I edit the code of google maps I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'https' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/asaav574/public_html/salumno11/app/config/Contactanos.php on line 10
```

Here the code:

```
class Contactanos {
    public $emails = array (    array ( 'nombre' => 'mi nombre','email' => correo@gmail.com',
)   ,)  ;
    public $GoogleMaps = '<iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zVd_LU3lNWZM.k8sTRRp8BROU" width="600" height="400"></iframe>';
    public $emailForm= 'micorreo@gmail.com';
}
```

I edit when I inserted the double quote but if I change the editor and I leave the single quote works correctly the issue is that my client is going to change this information and I will not leave this mistake when you make a change.

Comment: The array value `correo@gmail.com` is missing an opening `'`

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite this line:

```
public $emails = array (    array ( 'nombre' => 'mi nombre','email' => 'correo@gmail.com'));
```

An `'` was missing in front of the email, resulting in a parse error in the next line.

Generally in PHP when it say you have an error at a specific line, the error is in previous line.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer. It verda made a mistake when changing the provisional royal mail. Here is the code:

> class Contactanos {
>   public $emails = array (
>   array (   'nombre' => 'mi nombre', 'email' => 'micorreo@gmail.com',),
>   array (   'nombre' => '','email' => '',),
>   array (   'nombre' => '','email' => '',),
>   );
>   public $GoogleMaps = "";
>   public $emailForm= 'micorreo@gmail.com';
>   }